# Bind values to the listbox corresponding to the value selected in dropdownlist in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Here, I'm having a dropdownlist and a listbox. I have retrived data using DbContext and binded data for a dropdownlist using a Viewbag in my controller and displayed. Till here it works fine.

My controller..

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.StudentList = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentID", "StudentName");          
            return View();
        }
```

My View..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div>
     @Html.DropDownList("StudentList", "-Select-")
     <br/>
      @Html.ListBox("StudentMarks", new SelectList(""))
     <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
     </p>
    </div>
}
```

Now the problem is I need to bind data to the listbox according to the value selected in dropdownlist selected value. Initially, here it was an empty listbox.

Could anyone help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should get selected key from StudentList on 'onchange' event, then pass it to the server and get listbox values, then create 'option's for listbox's select with javascript

Answer (score 0):

At first write a change event for dropdownlist like,

```
$('#StudentList').change(function(){

var selecteditem=$('#StudentList').val();
$.ajax({
url:'Controller/Action',
type:'POST',
data:{id:selecteditem},
cache:false,
success:function(data){
var lstItems=[];
foreach(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
lstItems.push('<option value="'+data.Field1+'">data.Field2</option>');
}
$('#StudentMarks').empty();
$('#StudentMarks').append(lstItems);
}
});
});
```

and your action look like,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(string id)
{
// get all data by the student id.
return Json(listMarks,JsonRequestBehavior.Allow.Get);
}
```

This works for you.